# Symfony: Doctrine Update Foreign Key thru controller

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

my problem is that I have two entities customer and channel. The channel id is referenced in the customer table as a foreign key. And I'm trying to make a controller to update this column then editing the customer information in the backoffice with the country field that returns an number that corresponds to the id in the channel table. In mysql I'm trying to do

```sql
UPDATE voltalia.sylius_customer SET channel_id = 'id_channel' WHERE (id = 'customer');
```

My **Entity/Customer.php**:

```php
    <?php
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace App\Entity\Customer;
    
    use App\Entity\Channel\Channel;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Customer as BaseCustomer;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle\Configuration\Encrypted;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
     *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="lastName",
     *          column=@ORM\Column(name="last_name", nullable=true, type="string", length=7500)
     *     ),
     *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="firstName",
     *          column=@ORM\Column(name="first_name", nullable=true, type="string", length=7500)
     *     )
     * })
     * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_customer")
     */
    class Customer extends BaseCustomer implements CustomerInterface
    {
        public const STATE_NEW = 'new';
        public const STATE_TRUSTED = 'trusted';
    
        /**
         * @var CustomerType
         * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"sylius"}, message="voltalia.customer.require_accont_type")
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer\CustomerType")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $customerType;
    
        /**
         * @var string $taxNumber
         * @Encrypted()
         * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"sylius"})
         * @ORM\Column(name="tax_number", nullable=true, type="text")
         */
        private $taxNumber;
    
        /**
         * @var string $pecMail
         * @Encrypted()
         * @ORM\Column(name="pec_mail", nullable=true, type="text")
         */
        private $pecMail;
    
        /**
         * @var string $country
         * @Encrypted()
         * @ORM\Column(name="country", nullable=true, type="text")
         */
        private $country;
    
        /**
         * @var string $state
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="state", nullable=true, type="string")
         */
        private $state = self::STATE_NEW;
    
        /** @var string|null
         * @Encrypted
         */
        protected $firstName;
    
        /** @var string|null
         * @Encrypted
         */
        protected $lastName;
    
        protected $gender = CustomerInterface::UNKNOWN_GENDER;
    
        /** @var string|null
         * @Encrypted
         */
        protected $phoneNumber;
    
        /**
         * @var Channel
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Channel\Channel")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $registerChannel;
    
        /**
         * @return CustomerType | null
         */
        public function getCustomerType(): ?CustomerType
        {
            return $this->customerType;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param CustomerType | null $customerType
         */
        public function setCustomerType(?CustomerType $customerType): void
        {
            $this->customerType = $customerType;
        }
    
        public function isB2B(): bool
        {
            return $this->customerType !== null && $this->customerType->getCode() === 'B2B';
        }
    
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTaxNumber(): ?string
        {
            return $this->taxNumber;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param string $taxNumber
         */
        public function setTaxNumber(?string $taxNumber): void
        {
            $this->taxNumber = $taxNumber;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPecMail(): ?string
        {
            return $this->pecMail;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param string $pecMail
         */
        public function setPecMail(?string $pecMail): void
        {
            $this->pecMail = $pecMail;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCountry(): ?string
        {
            return $this->country;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param string $country
         */
        public function setCountry(?string $country): void
        {
            $this->country = $country;
        }
    
    
    
        /**
         * @return Channel
         */
        public function getRegisterChannel(): ?Channel
        {
            return $this->registerChannel;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Channel $registerChannel
         */
        public function setRegisterChannel(Channel $registerChannel): void
        {
            $this->registerChannel = $registerChannel;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return string
         */
    
        public function getState(): ?string
        {
            return $this->state;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param string $state
         */
        public function setState(?string $state): void
        {
            $this->state = $state;
        }
    }
```

My **Entity/Channel.php** is the default of sylius:

```php
    <?php
    
    /*
     * This file is part of the Sylius package.
     *
     * (c) Paweł Jędrzejewski
     *
     * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
     * file that was distributed with this source code.
     */
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Sylius\Component\Core\Model;
    
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\ZoneInterface;
    use Sylius\Component\Channel\Model\Channel as BaseChannel;
    use Sylius\Component\Currency\Model\CurrencyInterface;
    use Sylius\Component\Locale\Model\LocaleInterface;
    
    class Channel extends BaseChannel implements ChannelInterface
    {
        /** @var CurrencyInterface */
        protected $baseCurrency;
    
        /** @var LocaleInterface */
        protected $defaultLocale;
    
        /** @var ZoneInterface */
        protected $defaultTaxZone;
    
        /** @var string */
        protected $taxCalculationStrategy;
    
        /**
         * @var Collection|CurrencyInterface[]
         *
         * @psalm-var Collection<array-key, CurrencyInterface>
         */
        protected $currencies;
    
        /**
         * @var Collection|LocaleInterface[]
         *
         * @psalm-var Collection<array-key, LocaleInterface>
         */
        protected $locales;
    
        /** @var string */
        protected $themeName;
    
        /** @var string */
        protected $contactEmail;
    
        /** @var bool */
        protected $skippingShippingStepAllowed = false;
    
        /** @var bool */
        protected $skippingPaymentStepAllowed = false;
    
        /** @var bool */
        protected $accountVerificationRequired = true;
    
        /** @var ShopBillingDataInterface|null */
        protected $shopBillingData;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
    
            /** @var ArrayCollection<array-key, CurrencyInterface> $this->currencies */
            $this->currencies = new ArrayCollection();
            /** @var ArrayCollection<array-key, LocaleInterface> $this->locales */
            $this->locales = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBaseCurrency(): ?CurrencyInterface
        {
            return $this->baseCurrency;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setBaseCurrency(?CurrencyInterface $baseCurrency): void
        {
            $this->baseCurrency = $baseCurrency;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getDefaultLocale(): ?LocaleInterface
        {
            return $this->defaultLocale;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setDefaultLocale(?LocaleInterface $defaultLocale): void
        {
            $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getDefaultTaxZone(): ?ZoneInterface
        {
            return $this->defaultTaxZone;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setDefaultTaxZone(?ZoneInterface $defaultTaxZone): void
        {
            $this->defaultTaxZone = $defaultTaxZone;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getTaxCalculationStrategy(): ?string
        {
            return $this->taxCalculationStrategy;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setTaxCalculationStrategy(?string $taxCalculationStrategy): void
        {
            $this->taxCalculationStrategy = $taxCalculationStrategy;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getCurrencies(): Collection
        {
            return $this->currencies;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addCurrency(CurrencyInterface $currency): void
        {
            if (!$this->hasCurrency($currency)) {
                $this->currencies->add($currency);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function removeCurrency(CurrencyInterface $currency): void
        {
            if ($this->hasCurrency($currency)) {
                $this->currencies->removeElement($currency);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function hasCurrency(CurrencyInterface $currency): bool
        {
            return $this->currencies->contains($currency);
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getLocales(): Collection
        {
            return $this->locales;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addLocale(LocaleInterface $locale): void
        {
            if (!$this->hasLocale($locale)) {
                $this->locales->add($locale);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function removeLocale(LocaleInterface $locale): void
        {
            if ($this->hasLocale($locale)) {
                $this->locales->removeElement($locale);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function hasLocale(LocaleInterface $locale): bool
        {
            return $this->locales->contains($locale);
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getThemeName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->themeName;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setThemeName(?string $themeName): void
        {
            $this->themeName = $themeName;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getContactEmail(): ?string
        {
            return $this->contactEmail;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setContactEmail(?string $contactEmail): void
        {
            $this->contactEmail = $contactEmail;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function isSkippingShippingStepAllowed(): bool
        {
            return $this->skippingShippingStepAllowed;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setSkippingShippingStepAllowed(bool $skippingShippingStepAllowed): void
        {
            $this->skippingShippingStepAllowed = $skippingShippingStepAllowed;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function isSkippingPaymentStepAllowed(): bool
        {
            return $this->skippingPaymentStepAllowed;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setSkippingPaymentStepAllowed(bool $skippingPaymentStepAllowed): void
        {
            $this->skippingPaymentStepAllowed = $skippingPaymentStepAllowed;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function isAccountVerificationRequired(): bool
        {
            return $this->accountVerificationRequired;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function setAccountVerificationRequired(bool $accountVerificationRequired): void
        {
            $this->accountVerificationRequired = $accountVerificationRequired;
        }
    
        public function getShopBillingData(): ?ShopBillingDataInterface
        {
            return $this->shopBillingData;
        }
    
        public function setShopBillingData(ShopBillingDataInterface $shopBillingData): void
        {
            $this->shopBillingData = $shopBillingData;
        }
    }
```

And, for now, what I've tried is creating a controller for the client and using createQueryBuilder to update:

```php
    <?php
    
    
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use App\Entity\Channel\Channel;
    use App\Entity\Customer\Customer;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    
    
    
    class CustomerController extends AbstractController
    {
        /*
         *@Route("/admin/customers/{id}/edit", name="voltalia_update_channel", methods={"POST"})
         */
        public function updateChannel (Customer $customer, Channel $channel, $id, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        {
            $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
                ->update('channel_id', ':channel')
                ->setParameter('channel', $id)
                ->where('id',':customer')
                ->setParameter('id', $customer)
                ->getQuery()
            ;
    
        }
    }
```

And for now I can't update the field from this controller. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So in your controller action, if you have the `Customer`, `Channel`, and `EntityManagerInterface` injected correctly you can set the `Customer`'s `Channel` and use the `$entityManager` to update the Entity pretty easily.

```
// tell the EntityManager to track changes to entity/entities 
$entityManager->persist($customer);

// update entity/entities to suit your needs
$customer->setRegisterChannel($channel);

// tell the EntityManager to update tracked entities in the database
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: But how can I receive from the template an id and compare this id with the existing ones in the channel database and then define the channel with the same id?